# Métodos para resaltar botones

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy llenando algunos metodos para resaltar los botones de mis formularios en C# Windows Forms.

Por ejemplo MouseHover, MouseLeave.

Para al pasar el mouse encima del boton que este se resalte y al salir de el vuelva a su estado original.
Y al presionar el boton que tenga otro aspecto.

Pero me esta marcando error el primer método para resaltar el botón:
**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

```
 private void ResaltaButton()
    {

                DisableButton();
                currentButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255);//Aqui marca error
                currentButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
                currentButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Bahnschrift Condensed", 16.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                panelTitle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
```

A que se debe ese error de instanciamiento?

Saludos

DS

Comment: y que seria  currentbutton.. ahi parece que no es nada...

Comment: Quiero hacer referencia a los botones, en este caso boton actual.
private Button currentButton;
@gbianchi

Comment: Y donde decis que currentbutton es un boton obtenido de la interfaz? Ademas del codigo incompleto, el error te dice justamente eso

Comment: Eso es lo que intento o quiero, obtener el botón sobre el que esta el mouse.
Para no escribir en cada botón el código, del diseño que quiero tenga el boton.
@gbianchi

Comment: Tu pregunta es como saber el boton sobre cual se apoyo el mouse? En el evento onmouseeover, el sender es el control que recibio el evento. Investiga por a